# C# Acceso a Metodos privados

Tags: c#

Primero quiero ejemplificar con otro tema, antes de tocar el tema principal... leyendo el material teorico que tengo, si yo tengo un miembro de clase como por ejemplo

```
class Prueba
{
    public static void ejemplo()
{
Console.WriteLine("soy un ejemplo")
}
}
```

mi material dice que un miembro de clase solo puede ser llamado desde la misma clase y no desde la instancia de objeto creada, esto es correcto

```
Prueba.ejemplo() >>>>>>>>> output "soy un ejemplo"
```

Ahora el tema principal... segui leyendo este tema y me cruzo con los modificadores public y private y leo exactamente lo mismo, es decir que si tengo un metodo privado de una clase este solo puede ser accedido desdde la misma clase, pero como es la sintaxis para esto... por que estuve probando combinaciones y no llegue a nada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`public` y `private` son unos de los tantos modificadores de acceso utilizados para resaltar el contexto del objeto que estas definiendo.

Un modificador de acceso es aquel que se encarga de controlar las propiedades o métodos a los que puedes acceder en un objeto, considera el siguiente ejemplo:

```
public class MiObjeto 
{
    private int _X;
    public int X { get { return _X; } }
    publix void SetX(int x) 
    {
        _X = x;
    }
}
```

Al crear una nueva instancia de `MiObjeto`, defines una copia de la clase, en la cual puedes usar sus miembros public para obtener p ajustar su valor según sea necesario; al llamar al método `SetX(5)` el nuevo valor de la variable privada `_X` es 5, debido a que se accede desde un miembro público a un miembro privado.

Los miembros privados son aquellos a los que solo se pueden acceder desde dentro de la clase, es decir, cualquier método o función que sea publica o privada, tiene acceso a las demás propiedades de estos ambitos.

Con el código anterior, si en el `Main` hago:

```
MiObjeto Prueba = new MiObjeto();
Console.WriteLine(Prueba._X); // ERROR!
Console.WriteLine(Prueba.X); // Perfecto, imprime cero
Prueba.SetX(10);
Console.WriteLine(Prueba.X); // Imprime 10.
```

En resumen, los modificadores de acceso, controlan los métodos, los campos y propiedades que dejas que el usuario final puede utilizar y el comportamiento que puede manejar usando tu objeto.

### EDIT:

Con respecto al modificador `static`, su comportamiento rinde honor a su nombre, significa "estático", significa que no se mueve, que siempre está disponible, por lo que no necesitas una referencia para llamar a un método de este tipo.

Los modifcadores de acceso `public` y `private` pueden ser mezclados con `static` pero no entre ellos mismos:

```
private static int MiMiembro; // Bien
public static int OtroMiembro; // Perfecto
static char Caracter; // Todo bien
public private int KHE; //ERROR!
```

A lo que en adición menciono, existen ciertos puntos donde se presenta algo llamado "Inconsistencia de accesibilidad", esto pasa cuando asignas un modificador de acceso que no es compatible con cualquiera de los miembros de tu clase.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!!

Answer (score 0):

No creo que sea una buena práctica lo que pretendes hacer. Para eso son privados para que no se puedan acceder a ellos y utilizarlos por ejemplo para encapsular alguna lógica que quieras ocultar y/o reutilizar.

Fíjate si es así que aunque accedas a ellos mediante la librería System.Reflection no podrás acceder entonces a los métodos o propiedades pública. Los modificadores de acceso están para controlar esas cosas: public, private, protected e internal.